# Conditional formatting "is equal to" value in referenced cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

What do I add to the text field directly below the "is equal to" selection if I want the test to be the value of a specific cell?

I want the condition to pass and format a cell "IF" it is equal to the value in cell E1.

I've tried `=E1` and `E1`, but they're not working.

I know this is a simple one and I'm just missing something basic, but I can't figure it out and I've looked around.

[image: WA88996 question example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `=E$1` there. (Or, `=$E$1` if the formatted range spans multiple columns.)

Putting E1 would compare cells to the string "E1", which is not what you want.

Putting `=E1` compares the first cell in your column range to E1, the second to E2, the third to E3, etc -- because the reference is relative. The dollar sign makes it an absolute reference.

Comment: I knew it was something simple..... THANK YOU @Norma!